# StreamReader cannot read FileStream of code from referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, filestream, streamreader

I need to analyze Properites and Methods inside of classes in a custom framework that is being referenced by my active solution with a nuget package. 
I can read the files on my active solution successfully because I can use the local path of the file. 
I can also pull the FileStream of the file from the referenced framework assembly, but StreamReader is only reading "MZ�", and since the files are from a Nuget package, I do not have a local path.

Here are the three solutions I've tried and the problems I'm running in to in comments:

```
//attempt at using FileStream
                PortableExecutableReference location =
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(assemblyName).Location);
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(location.FilePath);
                FileStream f = assembly.GetFiles()
                    .Where(t => type.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (f != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
                    {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            fileString = sr.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //StreamReader does not read the FileStream, fileString value = "MZ�"

//attempt at geting the path thru f.Name
                PortableExecutableReference location =
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(assemblyName).Location);
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(location.FilePath);
                FileStream f = assembly.GetFiles()
                    .Where(t => type.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                return f.Name;
                //only returns the framework path. StreamReader can't read the file with this and since its metadata I can't find the file in framework solution.

//attempt to at least get the base class information
                Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(type));
                using (FileStream fs = a.GetFile(name))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                    {
                        return fileString = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
                //fs = null
```

fileString should contain my class file in the form of a string.

Answer (score 1):

The source code **isn't included** when you build a .NET program; it is compiled to IL (in a dense binary form, not as text IL source), and the IL is sent. The fact that you can do this *locally* is purely an accident of having the source files on your machine. This will not apply in general.

Basically, you're going to need a different option. .NET has a full reflection API, allowing you to inspect an awful lot of metadata at runtime (including fields, methods, properties, attributes, etc) - but it **does not** include the actual source code, because: you don't (usually) ship that.

If you can be more specific about what you need to *do* with what is currently `fileString`, we can probably guide you on the best approaches, and what is/isn't possible, etc.

Comment: I am using Roslyn syntax trees to parse through classes and pull out methods and properties, then displaying the values as strings in a form. Here's what I am using to parse methods from the classes in the active solution:                                SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(flowString);
 var syntaxRoot = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
 var method = syntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                .Where(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals("string"))
                .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @Kabberare you after names/signatures? Or the actual bodies? Names and signatures are available via reflection - the actual bodies ... not so much. You could consider embedding the source as a resource, but ... Eesh

Comment: @ Marc Gravell I'm after names and method bodies now and eventually I will need property names and values.

Comment: @Kabber property names and values are available via reflection, as are method names; method bodies aren't - you can get the IL, but that doesn't give you back original source, even if you ran it through a decompiler